# How many concurrent requests can a servlet handle in glassfish deployment?

Tags: java, servlets, threadpool

I'm developing a servlet that will be deployed in Glassfish 4.1
I'm wondering how many concurrent requests or "connections" can be made to a servlet for scalability purposes?

I've read that sometimes is 10, sometimes a thread pool can be used, but i haven't found a way to configure or read this info related to glassfish contained servlets.

Comment: This depends on the work your servlet does and what resources are available for it. You must provide more details for a usefull answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like the minimum is 2 and maximum is 5 as per this document  [Glassfish Performance tuning](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/performance-tuning-guide.pdf)